# Как достать элемент из словаря, в котором есть ещё один словарь

Tags: python

У меня есть словарь -

```
{"items":
    [{"match_id":"1-06234e07-cbf6-4ead-99a7-55bffc63402d",
     "game_id":"csgo", 
     "region":"EU",
     "match_type":"",
     "game_mode":"5v5",
     "max_players":10
```

и мне нужно из него как-то достать значение `match_id`
Как это сделать?